# Is there closed form for $\int_0^{\pi/4}\exp(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{2n}x}{n+a})\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Is there closed form for  $$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/4}\exp\left(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{2n}x}{n+a}\right)dx $$where is $a\in (-1,3)$

I've tried with $\tan x=u$ and I got the result of sum in term of HurwitzLerchPhi but I failed.

Comment: For $a=0$, we have $\displaystyle\sum=-\ln(1-\tan^2x)$, and $I(0)=\dfrac\pi2-1$.

Comment: For $a=1$, the integral becomes $I(1)=\displaystyle\frac e2\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt[\color{red}x]{1-x}}{1+x}\cdot\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}~,$ which, needless to say, does not look very promising. Similarly for $I(2)=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt e}2\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt[\color{red}x]e \cdot\sqrt[\color{red}{x^2}]{1-x}}{1+x}\cdot\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}~,$ which looks even more hopeless. Then $I\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)=\displaystyle e^2\int_0^1\sqrt[\color{red}x]{\frac{1-x}{1+x}} \cdot\frac{dx}{1+x^2}~,~$ and $I\bigg(-\dfrac12\bigg)=\displaystyle\int_0^1 \bigg(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\bigg)^{\color{red}x}\cdot\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{2n}x}{n+a}=\tan^2(x)\;\Phi\left(\tan^2(x)\;,\;1\;,\;1+a \right)$$

where $\Phi$ is Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-\tan^2(x)\;\Phi\left(\tan^2(x)\;,\;1\;,\;1+a\right)}dx $$
For a few particular values of $a$, the Hurwitz function reduces to a function of lower level. So, in particular cases, the integral is likely to have a closed form (for example in case of $a=0$).

But, in the general case,  it is highly unlikely that such an integral has a closed form.